# Covering/closing a basement drain, any reversible options?

Tags: plumbing, basement, drain-waste-vent

For a new basement-level room, we have the option of installing a drain or not installing a drain.

We're not sure yet what we want to do with the space.  It makes sense to have a drain installed while the floor is open.  If we later decide to improve the space, we know that we can't simply install flooring over the drain: water in the trap will evaporate and sewer gasses might get into the space.  OTOH we don't necessarily want to commit to the aesthetics of a drain in the middle of the room forever.

Is there some technology which would enable us to close the drain?  Even a "pluggable" drain would be a better option--anything reversible.

It's embarrassing to have too much space and not to know what to do with it, it's true :) , do we want a spa suite or do we want a library?  We can't decide.

Comment: My basement drains run into the sump with the sump pump and have been open without water for maybe 20 years, no notable orders of any type. They empty above the normal water level in the sump. I would assume the water has long since evaporated but that is just a guess. You could use a piece of vinyl cut to size and calked in. That would be gastite and removable.

Comment: It is usually better to have it and not need it.  A basement can stay dry for years, but something happens and it might flood/get wet/a pipe breaks.

Comment: It seems you are talking about 2 different things here- a "drain line" (to exit water from the basement if there was a flood/ broken pipe, etc.) and a "waste line" (which would drain a sink, toilet, shower etc.). A "waste line" would be tied into your sewer system- a "drain line" would most likely just exit the water to daylight in the yard or street. Either way you could pipe them and use a glue in plug or cap to seal the line from odors or bug intrusion. Preferably you would decide what you want where prior to doing your floor frame or slab. Then you would be able to properly plumb things.

Comment: Clean out type fittings are usually threaded for the cap.  Imagine there are some for flush mounting(without the square nut sticking up/out).  Not much difference between a clean out and a floor drain fitting.

Comment: @Gil your sump pump probably isn't plumbed into the sanitary sewer, so there's no sewer gas to escape back into the house through the lack of trap. Very much a different situation. Oh, if it _is_ plumbed into the sanitary sewer, your city/county would probably like to have a word with you about this (especially in the US - YMMV in other countries).

Comment: It is plumbed into the storm sewer, and it does have a check valve in its outlet. The floor drains are independent and empty into the sump, not directly into the sewer.